# Сравнение массива и ArrayList (примеры)

Tags: java

**Добавление элемента в конец массива**

**ArrayList**

```
list.add(str);
```

**Массив**
Невозможно выполнить данное действие (написано на ресурсе)

Разве нельзя сделать так:

```
int[] array = new int[10];
array[9] = 20; // добавил последний элемент в конец массива, 9 индекс == 10 элемент
```

**Вставка элемента в середину массива**

**ArrayList**

```
list.add(15, str);
```

**Массив**

Невозможно выполнить данное действие (написано на ресурсе)

Разве нельзя сделать вот так:

```
 int[] array = new int[10];
 array[5] = 10; // вставил элемент в середину массива
```

**Вставка элемента в начало массива**

**ArrayList**

```
list.add(0, str);
```

**Массив**

Невозможно выполнить данное действие (написано на ресурсе)

Разве нельзя сделать вот так:

```
 int[] array = new int[10];
 array[0] = 2; // вставил в начало массива
 array[1] = 4;
 array[2] = 6;
 array[3] = 8;
 array[4] = 10;
 array[0] = 24; // Вставил элемент в начало массива, но только (перезаписал значение)
```

Объясните по подробнее пожалуйста почему данные операции с массивами производить нельзя, заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему же нельзя? Можно, но только руками - увеличили длину массива (в Java явно создав новый массив и переписав данные), сдвинули часть массива, чтобы освободить место для нового элемента, записали новый элемент, вот и вставка готова.

Массив - простая и эффективная структура данных. Нужна легкая вставка? Используйте ArrayList, накладные расходы побольше, но часть работы от Вас спрятана.

Как, по-вашему, компилятор должен понять, что операция

```
 array[5] = 10;
```

должна в одном месте заменить элемент, а в другом - вставить новый с раздвижкой?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Да, но по сути и в других языках расширение динамического массива в большинстве случаев под капотом сводится к тому же.

Comment: я отдаю себе отчет что Вы это прекрасно понимаете, я оставил этот комментарий для тех кто мог бы не правильно это интерпретировать, но пока я это писал Вы уже все поправили =)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Не, как раз после этого комментария решил добавить ;)